# C++ How to update vectors that hold price and option for a code

Tags: c++, vector, output

I am writing a program where I input a txt file that has options for a car along with their prices into the program. The user chooses an option from the menu and chooses the model of the car. The price is updated and then the user is able to choose options. The options and the total price are updated in vectors.

I am having trouble updating the price and options added. I add the names of the options, but the options or price are not updating.

I know structures might have been easier but I need to do this program using vectors.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

//function signature
void showMenu();
void printOptions();
char getModel();
void displaySelection(char model, double totalCost, vector<string> &options);
bool isEqual(string str1, string str2);

void addOption (char model, double &totalCost, vector <double> &price, vector <string> &optionsSelected, vector <string> &optionsAvailable);
void removeOption (char model, double totalCost, vector <double> price, vector <string> optionsSelected, vector <string> optionsAvailable);

// main function to run the program
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{
    // print a welcome message
   cout << "Bobcats Auto Dealership" << endl;
   // declare variables
   int menuChoice;
   char model = ' ';
   double totalCost = 0;
   vector<double> price;
   vector<string> optionsAvailable;
   vector<string> optionsSelected;

   // read input from file
   ifstream inStream("options.txt");

   if (inStream.fail())
    {
       cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
       exit (0);
   }

   while (!inStream.eof())
    {
       // first input is price of option
       int cost;
       inStream >> cost; // get price of option
       // rest of line is option details
       string option;
       getline(inStream, option);
       // add price to price list
       price.push_back(cost);
       // add option
       if (option[0] == ' ')
       {
           option = option.substr(1, option.length() - 1); // ignore white space at start of option name
       }
       optionsAvailable.push_back(option);
   }

   // show menu and ask for option till user select quit
   while (menuChoice != 6)
    {
       cout << endl; // print empty line
       // display user selected option
       displaySelection(model, totalCost, optionsSelected);
       // show menu for next selection
       showMenu();
       cin >> menuChoice; // get user input
       // check for valid input

       if (menuChoice < 0 || menuChoice>6)
        {
           cout << "Invalid menu choice" << endl;
       }



       if (menuChoice ==1)
       {
           if (model == ' ') 
           {
               model = getModel();
               // check the model and add cost

               if (model == 'E') {
                   totalCost = 10000.0;
               }
               else if (model == 'L') {
                   totalCost = 12000.0;
               }
               else {
                   // model is X
                   totalCost = 18000.0;
               }
           }
       }

      else if (menuChoice ==2)
      {

           printOptions();
      }

       else if (menuChoice == 3 ) 
       {

         addOption(model, totalCost, price, optionsSelected, optionsAvailable);


          /** if (model != ' ')
            {
               cout << "Enter option: ";
               string option_name;
               cin.ignore(); // ignore newline character
               getline(cin, option_name); // get option name from user
               // check if option is available
               for (size_t i = 0; i < optionsAvailable.size(); i++) {
                   if (isEqual(optionsAvailable.at(i),option_name)) {
                       // check if user already selected that option
                       bool isSelected = false;
                       for (size_t j = 0; j < optionsSelected.size(); j++) {
                           if (isEqual(optionsSelected.at(i),optionsSelected.at(j))) {
                               isSelected = true; // set flag to true
                           }
                       }
                       // add option to selected option if not already selected
                       if (!isSelected) {
                           optionsSelected.push_back(optionsAvailable.at(i));
                           // add cost of option
                           totalCost = totalCost + price.at(i);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           */
       }

      else if (menuChoice ==4 )
        {
            removeOption ( model, totalCost, price, optionsSelected, optionsAvailable);
           /**if (model != ' ') {
               cout << "Enter option: ";
               string option_name;
               cin.ignore(); // ignore newline character
               getline(cin, option_name); // get option name from user
               // check if option is seleced
               for (size_t i = 0; i < optionsSelected.size(); i++) {
                   if (isEqual(optionsSelected.at(i),option_name)) {
                       // remove cost of option
                       for (size_t j = 0; j < optionsAvailable.size(); j++) {
                           if (isEqual(optionsSelected.at(i), optionsAvailable.at(j))) {
                               totalCost = totalCost - price.at(j);
                           }
                       }
                       // remove option from selected option
                       optionsSelected.erase(optionsSelected.begin() + i);
                   }
               }
           }
           */
        }

       else if (menuChoice ==5) 
       {
           // cancel order and start new one
           model = ' ';
           totalCost = 0;
           optionsSelected.clear();
       }
   }
   while (menuChoice != 6);

   return 0;
}




// function implementaion
void displaySelection(char model,double totalCost, vector<string> &options)
 {
   // check if order is started
   if (model == ' ') {
       cout << "NO MODEL SELECTED" << endl;
   }
   else {
       // print model
       cout << "Model: " << model  << ", $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << totalCost << endl;
       cout << "Options: ";
       // check for options
       if (options.size() > 0) {
           // print all options
           for (size_t i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) 
           {
               // print 3 options per line
               if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0)
                {
                   cout << endl;
                }
               // print each option
               cout << options.at(i);
               // add commas
               if (i < options.size() - 1) {
                   cout << ", ";
               }
           }
       }
       else {
           cout << "None";
       }
       cout << endl; // print newline
   }
}

void showMenu() 
{
   cout << "1. Select a model(E, L, X)" << endl;
   cout << "2. Display available options and prices" << endl;
   cout << "3. Add an option" << endl;
   cout << "4. Remove an option" << endl;
   cout << "5. Cancel order" << endl;
   cout << "6. Quit" << endl;
   cout << "Enter choice: " << endl;
}

void printOptions()
{
   cout << " " << endl;

    cout << "Prices for model E, L, & X: $10,000, $12,000, $18,000" << endl;
    cout << "Available Options" <<endl;
    cout << "" << endl; 
    cout << "Leather Seats ($5000)            Dvd System ($1000)          10 Speakers" << endl;
    cout << "Navigation System ($1400)        CarPlay ($500)              Android Auto ($500)" << endl;
    cout << "Lane Monitoring ($2000)          3/36 Warranty ($800)        6/72 Warranty ($999)" << endl;
    cout << "Dual Climate ($1500)             Body Side Molding ($225)    Cargo Net ($49)" << endl;
    cout << "Cargo Organizer ($87)            450W Audio ($700)           Heated Seats ($1000)" << endl;     
}

char getModel()
 {
   string model = "S";
   cin.ignore(); // ignore newline character
   // promt user for model till valid model is selected
   while (true) {
       cout << "Enter the model (E, L, X): ";
       getline(cin, model);
       // check for valid model
       if (model.length() == 1) {
           char c = toupper(model[0]);
           if (c=='E' || c=='L' || c=='X') {
               model = "";
               model = model + c;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   return model[0];
}

bool compareChar(char& c1, char& c2) {
   if (toupper(c1) == toupper(c2)) {
       return true;
   }
   else {
       return false;
   }
}
bool isEqual(string str1, string str2) 
{
   return (str1.size() == str2.size() && equal(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), &compareChar));
}

void addOption (char model, double &totalCost, vector <double> &price, vector <string> &optionsSelected, vector <string> &optionsAvailable)
{
if (model != ' ')
     {
         cout << "Enter option: ";
         string option_name;
         cin.ignore(); // ignore newline character
         getline(cin, option_name); // get option name from user
         // check if option is available
         for (size_t i = 0; i < optionsAvailable.size(); i++) 
               {
                if (isEqual(optionsAvailable.at(i),option_name)) {
                 // check if user already selected that option
                bool isSelected = false;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < optionsSelected.size(); j++)
                 {
                    if (isEqual(optionsSelected.at(i),optionsSelected.at(j))) 
                    {
                        isSelected = true; // set flag to true
                    }
                 }
                       // add option to selected option if not already selected
                 if (!isSelected) 
                 {
                     optionsSelected.push_back(optionsAvailable.at(i));
                     // add cost of option
                    totalCost = totalCost + price.at(i);
                 }
                   }
               }
           }

}


void removeOption (char model, double totalCost, vector <double> price, vector <string> optionsSelected, vector <string> optionsAvailable)
{
    if (model != ' ') 
        {
               cout << "Enter option: ";
               string option_name;
               cin.ignore(); // ignore newline character
               getline(cin, option_name); // get option name from user
               // check if option is seleced
               for (size_t i = 0; i < optionsSelected.size(); i++)
                {
                   if (isEqual(optionsSelected.at(i),option_name)) 
                   {
                       // remove cost of option
                       for (size_t j = 0; j < optionsAvailable.size(); j++)
                        {
                           if (isEqual(optionsSelected.at(i), optionsAvailable.at(j))) {
                               totalCost = totalCost - price.at(j);
                           }
                       }
                       // remove option from selected option
                       optionsSelected.erase(optionsSelected.begin() + i);
                   }
               }
           }
}
```

edit: 
This is What options.txt has:
5000.0 Leather Seats
1000.0 DVD System
800.0 10 Speakers
1400.0 Navigation System
500.0 CarPlay
500.0 Android Auto
2000.0 Lane Monitoring
800.0 3/36 Warranty
999.0 6/72 Warranty
1500.0 Dual Climate
225.0 Body Side Molding
49.0 Cargo Net
87.0 Cargo Organizer
700.0 450W Audio
1000.0 Heated Seats

Comment: Not necessarily the problem you're asking about, but a problem with your code: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/2027196)

Comment: Also a problem you're going to run into: [Why does std::getline skip input after a formatted extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/2027196)

Comment: What is your Textfile `options.txt` containing? (Maybe add an example to the question)